# Initializing a null pointer before fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

So I gotta make this program that reads a huge .txt file into an AVL, and for that, I need to read all the formatted data in the text document and put it into an AVL. However, any time I try to initialize the AVL in my code (a NULL pointer) it breaks the code once it reaches the fscanf function I used to gather the strings out of the .txt file. I made this demo right here, and I think I'm pretty close to the source of the problem. I narrowed it down to being related to initializing a pointer with a NULL value before the fscanf function. But how do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE * filePointer = fopen("_lexico_shuf.txt", "r");

    if(!filePointer) {
        printf("can't open the file");
        exit(101);
    }

    char *lexiconWord;
    float polarity;

    int *a = NULL;
    printf("before while");
    while (!feof(filePointer)) {
        fscanf(filePointer, "%[^;];%f\n", lexiconWord, &polarity);
        printf("| (%s) (%.1f) |", lexiconWord, polarity);
    }
    printf("after while");

}
```

so the only thing that is printed on the screen is the "before while" printf, and not the "after while" one. and the program returns a random number.

Comment: Before using the result of `fscanf`, you should verify that the function was successful. See this question for further information: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Comment: Please [edit] and format your code properly and show the first 8-9 lines of your `_lexico_shuf.txt` file.

Comment: Lucas Nascimento, Who or what text suggest code like `while (!feof(filePointer)) {`?

Comment: Closed for wrong primary reason.  OP's main issue is `lexiconWord` is uninitialized when `fscanf(filePointer, "%[^;];%f\n", lexiconWord, ...` called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lexiconWord` hasn't been set to point anywhere, so `fscanf` is using an invalid pointer value to attempt to write to.

Change this variable to an array, and use a field width in `fscanf` do you don't overrun the buffer, and check the return value of `fscanf`.

```
char lexiconWord[100];
...
int rval = fscanf(filePointer, "%99[^;];%f\n", lexiconWord, &polarity);
if (rval != 2) {
    printf("not all values read\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Nope, never touched it.  The term "field width" is used in the standard and the man pages.

Comment: Why yes it is!.. "An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width (in characters)."